# Handling errors in lexical analysis

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a lexical analyzer and I would like it to output meaningful and accurate error messages. Like the exact line and column where errors occurred. What's the appropriate way of handling errors when writing a lexical analyzer?

Answer (score 2):

What tools are you using for lexical analysis? I know a little **Flex**, I'll just write it down what I know, maybe its helpful for you or someone else.

Flex is a tool used commonly for generating lexical analyzers. Instead of writing one from scratch, you only need to tell it how your tokens are (using regular expressions), and it will generate a C program which gives a stream of tokens from the input character stream.

Its easy to learn, here's a good [tutorial](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~bvz/cs461/notes/flex/). After learning it, you will be able to report errors easily.

Regarding line numbers, Flex defines a variable called `yylineno` which holds the current line number. For column numbers, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656703/how-does-flex-support-bison-location-exactly) might help.