# Processing location information bison c++ parser error

Tags: c++, bison

I'm working on a bison c++ parser.
Most examples has error method with parameter `location&` in .y file, but I'm not sure how to get the location_type to call this method.

```
typedef location location_type;
void
yy::c_parser::error (const location_type& l,
                          const std::string& m)
{
  driver.error (l, m);
}
```

This is an example excerpt from http://panthema.net/2007/flex-bison-cpp-example/,

```
if (!driver.calc.existsVariable(*$1)) {
           error(yyloc, std::string("Unknown variable \"") + *$1 + "\"");
```

However, I got an error that `parser.yy:109: error: ‘yyloc’ was not declared in this scope` when compiling it.

Comment: May be related to [SO/how-does-flex-support-bison-location-exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656703/how-does-flex-support-bison-location-exactly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is slightly unclear: where do you want to call `yyerror` from?

If you want to call it from the parser, then just use the `@n` pseudo-variables:

```
exp: exp "/" exp
  {
    if (!$3)
      {
         yyerror(@3, "division by zero");
         YYERROR;
      }
    else
      {
         $$ = $1 / $3;
      }
  }
```

If you want to call it from the scanner, then use the variable used there to denote the current location, probably something like `yylloc`.

If you want to call it from elsewhere (e.g., from an AST traversal, but that would be weird), then find the location there.

But more importantly (sorry, I may state something that you already know): be aware that you typically do not need to call `yyerror`: you have to *provide* it, so that parser can raise errors.  Typical calls to `yyerror` are in the generated code, not in code you are expected to write.

Comment: Where is yyloc defined? Error: Undeclared identifier. I can't locate it in the bison parser files.

Comment: It depends what you are looking for: location in the scanner, in the parser?  One the scanner side, I don't know what name you chose.  In the grammar rules, that's @n.  In other places, such as yyerror, it's an additional argument.  Also, what language?  Read the documentation for all the details.  For instance in C++: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Location-Values.html.

Comment: I was trying to enable locations for this example :https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/A-Simple-C_002b_002b-Example.html#A-Simple-C_002b_002b-Example The method signatures change with locations enabled. Now, the user-defined makexxx methods don't have access to the location object and the symbol_type constructors need location_type as parameter. I'm new to Bison and Flex.

Comment: You have an example using locations and make_* functions [here](https://github.com/akimd/bison/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/variant-11.yy).

Comment: Thanks @akim. I did assume that the location object would have to be created. Just wasn't sure what to fill into its contents.