# Flex/Bison 'yylex' : function does not take 3 arguments

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have the following Lexer.l and Parser.y files.

Lexer.l

```
%{
#include "Parser.h"
%}

%option yylineno
%option outfile="Lexer.cpp" header-file="Lexer.h"
%option warn nodefault
%option reentrant noyywrap never-interactive nounistd
%option bison-bridge
```

Parser.y

```
%{
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Lexer.h"

extern int yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, const char *msg) 
{printf("\r\nError: %s", msg); return 1;}

%}
 
%code requires {     
#ifndef YY_TYPEDEF_YY_SCANNER_T
#define YY_TYPEDEF_YY_SCANNER_T
typedef void* yyscan_t;
#endif
}
 
%output  "Parser.cpp"
%defines "Parser.h"     
%define api.pure
%pure-parser
%lex-param   { yyscan_t scanner }
%parse-param {yyscan_t scanner }
```

Everything works fine.

Now I am trying to get the column and line for a token; when I use ***@1.first_line*** I get the following errors:

> 'yylex' : function does not take 3 arguments
>
> 'yyerror' : function does not take 3 arguments

For the yyerror I looked at the compiler requirements for it and implemented it.

But, for yylex I have no idea what to return.
I've tried to look at the yylex with 2 parameters implementation to make something similar, but it seems to be no implementation for yylex at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `option bison-bridge` and your parser has `@` references, you need to add

```
%option bison-locations
```

to your flex file. (You can use it instead of bison-bridge, but I think it is tidier to have both.) From the [`flex` manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options.html):

- `--bison-locations, %option bison-locations`

  - instruct flex that GNU bison `%locations` are being used.  This
    means `yylex` will be passed an additional parameter, `yylloc`.
    This option implies `%option bison-bridge`.

Comment: I did that and it worked. But always all properties are 1. I have tried to modify the line/colum like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656703/how-does-flex-support-bison-location-exactly) but I get 'yyg': undeclared variable

Comment: @dragos: That's too complicated a question to answer in a comment. Also, the question you link to has six answers, which are subtly different; you'll need to show an example of your code (as small as possible, but still self-contained). Please ask a new question with this information. Thanks.

Comment: I actually tried all of them - in the end the same error. 
But I figure it out: I changed in their examples the yyloc with the function **yyget_lloc** and it worked.Thank you for your answers.