# Does Flex (lexical analysis) have no implementation of a column number?

Tags: c, gcc, bison, flex-lexer, windows-11

I am already using yylineno in my Flex, Bison, and C project. However, I would also like to use a column number to pinpoint the exact location of a lexical error on a particular line. Does Flex have no implementation of a column number? The only reason I can of is because the tab character '\t' can be set to accept to any number of spaces. If there is already an implementation I would like to use instead of reinventing the wheel.

I have searched through the book "Lexical Analysis with Flex", Edition 2.6.0, 10 November 2015 by Vern Paxson, Will Estes and John Millaway. I also searched Google but no luck. I hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Did you just ask this exact same question with almost exactly the same text, referencing the exactly same book? Don't do that! Improve the first question you have instead.

Comment: I deleted that question because I couldn't remove the tag "flexbox". I actually typed in "flex" but instead it added flexbox (don't know how). It was too late. I had already posted that question. I couldn't how to delete that tag. So, I just deleted the question and started over.

Comment: There's an `Edit` link right below the tags. That allows you to edit your whole question, including the tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Flex (lexical analysis) have no implementation of a column number?

Flex does not track a position on the current line for you.

However, you might be interested in Flex's [`bison-locations`](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Ecr4bd/flex-manual/Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options.html#index-bison_002dlocations) option, which works together with Bison's [`locations`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Decl-Summary.html#index-_0025locations) feature.

Note that Flex does provide [`yylen`](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Ecr4bd/flex-manual/User-Values.html#index-yyleng-1), the length of the current token, and it recognizes [`YY_USER_ACTION`](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Ecr4bd/flex-manual/Misc-Macros.html#index-YY_005fUSER_005fACTION), which you can use to insert code before every action.  Between these, it is relatively easy to track the position on the line manually.

You can find more information in [How does flex support bison-location exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656703/2402272)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it very much. I will try bison-locations.